# Render a partial view inside a Jquery modal popup ( 2 different models)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My project is room-Booking. I have View which on model of rooms displays id of the room and her characteristic on foreach:

```
@model IEnumerable<Room>

<div class="roomConteiner">
        @foreach (Room room in Model)
        {
                <table class="simple-little-table" cellspacing='0'>
                    <tr>
                        <td> @room.NumberRoom </td>
                        <td>@room.Categoryid</td>
                        <td> @room.NumberOfSeats </td>
                        <td> @room.CostPerNight </td>
                        <td>

                            <button class="roomBookingButton" data-roomid="@room.Id">Booking</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

And I have JS, which On buttonClick  Render a partial view inside a Jquery modal popup:

```
</script>

<div id="dialog-modal" > @Html.Partial("UserPartial", new Client()) </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        resizable: false
    });

    $('.roomConteiner').on("click", ".roomBookingButton", function () {

        $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
    });
});
</script>
```

UserPartial:

```
  @model Client
    <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Surname")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Surname)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Name")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Booking" />
```

How to transfer NumberRoom in popup window from foreach? That, for example, in popup window gave out to me : "you chose the room number 5" please fill in your data: name,surname.......

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult UserPartial()
        { 
            return PartialView("UserPartial" , new Client());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact same question as posted by the user "Alex Da".

[Render a partial view inside a Jquery modal popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975413/render-a-partial-view-inside-a-jquery-modal-popup/)

To answer your question about getting the ID, you can get that value:

```
$(".roomBookingButton").on("click", function () {
  var id = $(this).data("roomid");

  // make call to your partial action
  $.get('@Url.Action("UserPartial", "Home")', { id: id }, function (view) {
    $("dialog-modal").html(view);
  });
});
```

And then adjust your partial view action:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult UserPartial(int id)
{
  var client = db.Clients.Single(id);

  return PartialView("UserPartial" , client);
}
```

And that's it.

Comment: 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Hotel.BusinessObject.Client>' does not contain a definition for 'Single' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Single<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: public PartialViewResult SaveUserDBPartial(string numberRoom)
        {
            var client = db.Client.Single(numberRoom);
            return PartialView("SaveUserDBPartial" , client);
        }        Error(((((

Comment: You should edit your original question to include the relationship between "rooms" and "client".  As far as I can tell, there is currently no link between selecting a room and displaying client info...  The only information you give us is that rooms have an ID.  How does this room ID factor into displaying client data?

Comment: what information for project you need to help me? between rooms and clients communicate across the table  booking  and roombooking.......Client-Booking-RoomBoking-Room

Comment: When someone clicks the "Booking" button, you want a modal to pop-up with the model [Client] that contains the properties "Surname" and "Name".  My question to you is HOW is this [Client] model related to the [Room] model?  Do they share a foreign key?  There needs to be a relationship between the two models to display the correct [Client] data in your modal popup.

Comment: Directly these models aren't connected (communications - the foreign key isn't present). they are connected with the intermediate tables Client (id) - Booking(ClientId) - RoomBooking (BookingId, RoomId) - Room(Id)